# Linq or EF - Multiple join into non anonymous object with filtered attributes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am using EF and unfortunately includefiltered is not option. So I have to rewrite my code somehow and create non anonymous object from it. I decided to rewrite it to join but it can be anything that works.

I have entity, simplified version Car.Tires.Manufacturers.
Car can have zero to many tires, tires can have zero to many manufacturers

I want to get car with specific id and only it's tires with specific manufacturer.
The problem is that my result car's tires always have null manufacturers.

My current code is :

```
 var car1 = (from c in this.dbContext.Cars
                            .Include(cr => cr.Tires)
                            .ThenInclude(crt => crt.Manufacturers)

            join t in this.dbContext.Tires
                            .Include(ct => ct.Manufacturers)
                      on c.ID equals t.CarID into carTires

       from t in carTires.DefaultIfEmpty()
       join m in this.dbContext.Manufacturers on t.ManufacturerID equals m.ID into completeSet

       from cs in completeSet.DefaultIfEmpty()
       where (c.ID == someCarID ) // and later I will add filter for tire's manufacturer


       select new Car
       {
          ID = c.ID,
          Tires = c.Tires
       }
```

If I use code

```
       var car2 = this.dbContext.Cars
                .Include(c => c.Tires)
                    .ThenInclude(t => t.Manufacturers)
                Where(c => c.ID == someCarID)
```

In Car2 there are some manufacturers.

Why car1 Tire's manufacturers is null and how to fix it?

Note: This is middle goal. My final goal is to obtain car with tires only for selected manufacturer.

Comment: If you are manually joining your data (using dbcontext), you shouldn't also need to specify all those include statements.

Comment: I have it there out of desperateness

Comment: Do you need to stick to the approach for `car1`? If not, you might as well expand on the (working) approach for `car2`.

Comment: @jcruz I actually more like the car2 approach but unfortunately I do not know how to solve it without IncludeFiltered() which I cannot use. As the real problem is more complex and i need to filter one of it's attribute descendant according to selected ID and then obtain values from another child attribute of that filtered descendant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var manufacturerTires = dbContext.Tires.Where(t => t.ManufacturerID == someManufacturerID);

var carTires = dbContext.Cars.
        Where(car => car.ID == someCarID)
        .Join(manufacturerTires,
              car => car.ID,
              tire => tire.CarID,
              (car, tire) => new { car, tire })
        .ToList();
```

This should return an anonymous object `new { Car, Tire }`

if we need to get the existing structure of Car and Car.Tires, we could add a GroupBy at the end of the above query like:

```
.GroupBy(c => c.car, c => c.tire, (car, tires) => new Car{ ID = car.ID, Tires = tires}); 
//this could be an expensive query as the GroupBy is on all the columns in Car table
```

Comment: Thanks, that pushed me the way I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var Cars=this.dbContext.Cars.Where(c => c.ID == someCarID).Select(s=> s.Tires).ToList();
```

Now you have tires with there Manufacturers

Comment: Thanks. And what if we go deeper and make it more complex? What if car also have Gears and gear has vendor and vendor has manufacturer? And I want both tires and gears in object with all descendant attributes.

Comment: I see, in this case you can use Linq like :

(from c in this.dbContext.Cars
            join t in this.dbContext.Tires
                      on c.ID equals t.CarID 
 join m in this.dbContext.Manufacturers on t.ManufacturerID equals m.ID
where c.ID='XXXX'
select c).ToList();